# Cordova blackberry convenience key

Tags: javascript, cordova, blackberry

I want to reprogram my Blackberry convenience key using Cordova.

```
document.addEventListener("volumeupbutton", onVolumeUpKeyDown, false);

function onVolumeUpKeyDown() {
    // Handle the volume up button
}
```

I get the above code to handle the volume keys. But how can I handle blackberry convenience key in Cordova?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: [`deviceEvents.js`](https://github.com/blackberry/cordova-blackberry/blob/master/framework/lib/events/deviceEvents.js#L23-L39) and [`events.js`](https://github.com/blackberry/cordova-blackberry/blob/master/framework/lib/event.js) but they are not associated to a `keypress`. You can read their [api docs](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/files/blackberry-dynamics/cordova/) and [guide](https://docs.blackberry.com/en/development-tools/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-cordova/4_2/blackberry-dynamics-sdk-cordova-devguide/bkr1503522170649).

Comment: this may be impossible to accomplish, you may have to read blackberry source and find out that it is impossible to build a webview which subscribes to their blackbarry native code for keyevents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is one. Cordova documentation doesn't offer anything beyond standard key events. You can try to implement your own in Java, name it "conveniencebutton" and later listen to it. You can take a look here:
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/ce531545557e8da782d0640a8749199edc8dcf5f/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewImpl.java#L557-L600